# How to incorporate proxies with my code (Instaloader python module)

Tags: python, proxy

I was trying to find out how to incorporate proxies in my code and was directed to this webpage https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies . They tell me to do the following

```
  import requests

  proxies = {
    'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
    'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
  }

  requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

How am I supposed to incorporate this in my code?
Here is my code so far

```
  import requests
  import instaloader
  L = instaloader.Instaloader()

  # Login or load session
  L.login(username, password)        # (login)


  # Obtain profile metadata
  profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "prada")

  # Print list of followees
  file = open("prada_followers.txt","a+")

  for followee in profile.get_followers():
     username = followee.username
     file.write(username + "\n")
     print(username)

  file.close()
```

Comment: I'm also wondering how can you do that, but I think that its not possible. I think that Instaloader lib has some built in proxies, but Its very hard to pass this trough Instagram security

Comment: But, maybe (and I do not know how to do that), you can write a code that will change your IP address every 2,5,...n requests , but again, I do not know how to do this

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
proxies = {}

# # in case proxy is from free-proxy-list
# proxies = {
#   'http': f"http://{proxy}",
#   'https': f"https://{proxy}"
# }

# # in case of proxy broker
# parsed = urlparse(proxy)
# proxies = {
#   'http': f"http://{parsed.hostname}:{parsed.port}",
#   'https': f"https://{parsed.hostname}:{parsed.port}"
# }

# # in case of tor proxy running on localhost
# proxies = {
#     'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
#     'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
# }
```

```
loader.context._session.proxies = proxies
```

is how I used to do it